# Issue Connecting to ADFS using SAML2 protocol (using Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin package)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2, adfs4.0

I'm new to SAML 2.0 signing protocol.

Currently in my MVC application I'm using WS federation as signing protocol, now I have to use SAML 2.0 signing protocol.

Our IDP is ADFS and AUTH Plugin is Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin package

First I are trying to connect with SAML 2.0 signing protocol without self signed certificate.

For that in AFDS I have set **Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust** is already set to false

[please refer below screenshot of ADFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uPtU.png)

When trying to access the application after providing login info getting below error

**Error details: MSIS7085: The server requires a signed SAML authentication request but no signature is present.**

When I decrypted the SAML response with the help of fiddler, found incorrect saml2:Issuer value

after decrypting SAML request listed below

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="id95832a0e04ac48d7a3d33d7a185f4906" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-02-08T08:47:26Z" Destination="https://dummy.com/adfs/ls/" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://dummy.dev/Saml2/Acs">
  <saml2:Issuer>**http://dummy.com/adfs/services/trust**</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

but the correct SAML request should have below listed  saml2:Issuer value

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="id95832a0e04ac48d7a3d33d7a185f4906" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-02-08T08:47:26Z" Destination="https://dummy.com/adfs/ls/" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://dummy.dev/Saml2/Acs">
  <saml2:Issuer>**https://dummy.dev**</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Please help me how to define saml2:Issuer in application code side , so that in SAML request it works perfectly.

Please let me known if any other information is required.

Thanks in advance...

Need SAML 2.0 as signing protocol for connecting with IDP as ADFS by using  Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin package